# Unix: traverse a directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I need to traverse a directory so starting in one directory and going deeper into difference sub directories. However I also need to be able to have access to each individual file to modify the file. Is there already a command to do this or will I have to write a script? Could someone provide some code to help me with this task? Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of the traversal?

Answer (score 5):

The `find` command is just the tool for that. Its -exec flag or -print0 in combination with `xargs -0` allows fine-grained control over what to do with each file.

Example: Replace all foo's by bar's in all files in /tmp and subdirectories.

```
find /tmp -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/' '{}' ';'
```

Comment: @thiton Using `sed` you will not access the files interactively. I don't think this is what @EricAnderson was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in `find` ; do
  if [ -d $i ] ; then do something with a directory ; fi
  if [ -f $i ] ; then do something with a file etc. ; fi
done
```

This will return the whole tree (recursively) in the current directory in a list that the loop will go through.

Comment: Nice example but its not safe if there are special characters such as spaces in the filenames or directory names.

Comment: +1 agreed. There's a lot more to that as well (error handling). I just tried to illustrate find's behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily achieved by mixing `find`, `xargs`, `sed` (or other file modification command).

For example:
`$ find /path/to/base/dir -type f -name '*.properties' | xargs sed -ie '/^#/d'`

This will filter all files with file extension `.properties`.
The `xargs` command will feed the `file path` generated by `find` command into the `sed` command.
The `sed` command will delete all lines start with `#` in the files (feed by `xargs`).

Command combination in this way is very flexible.

For example, `find` command have different parameters so you can filter by user name, file size, file path (eg: under /test/ subfolder), file modification time.

Another dimension of flexibility is how and what to change in your file. For ex, `sed` command allows you to make changes on file in applying substitution (specify via regular expressions). Similarly, you can use `gzip` to compress the file. And so on ...

Answer (score 1):

You would usually use the [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) command.  On Linux, you have the [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/find.html) version, of course.  It has many extra (and useful) options.  Both will allow you to execute a command (eg a shell script) on the files as they are found.

The exact details of how to make changes to the file depend on the change you want to make to the file.  That is probably best scripted, with `find` running the script:

POSIX or GNU:

```
find . -type f -exec your_script '{}' +
```

This will run your script once for a group of files with those names provided as arguments.  If you want to do it one file at a time, replace the `+` with `';'` (or `\;`).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `SearchMe` is the example directory name you need to traverse completely.
I am also assuming, since it was not specified, the files you want to modify are all text file. Is this correct?

In such scenario I would suggest using the command:

```
find SearchMe -type f -exec vi {} \;
```

If you are not familiar with `vi` editor, just use another one (`nano`, `emacs`, `kate`, `kwrite`, `gedit`, etc.) and it should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Bash 4+

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **
do
    if [ -f "$file" ];then
        # do some processing to your file here
        # where the find command can't do conveniently        
    fi
done
```